# How to use ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Item() property

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to use the `Item()` property of `ComboBox` objects.  It is listed on MSDN @:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.aspx

However, I have no luck finding an example with that property.  I cannot pull it up using something like:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Item(0);
```

or

```
ComboBox1.Item(0);
```

even though I am able to have

```
ComboBox1.Items.Count();
```

Can someone help me?  Actually the main goal is to pull the names of the items inside the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `Items(0)` and not `Item(0)`. Also since it is **C#**. Try using

```
ComboBox1.Items[0];
```

[image]

Comment: I am talking about this Property:

Comment: So did it answer your question?

Comment: YES, you did.  It is actually Combobox1.Item[#].  


I lost my connection before finishing the question earlier.  MSDN has 'Item' Property listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.item.aspx

I wonder what that one is.  I can never get to it.